# Check if last 10 rows duplicated

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to code a php script, which can find if the last 10 rows from mySQL database are the same. And if the values are same, then the script could sent an email.

I can fetch the last 10 rows.

```
$sql = ("SELECT ID, DayTime,Temperature FROM AllinOne ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10");
    
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "id: " . $row["ID"]. " - DayTime: " . $row["DayTime"]. " - Temperature " . $row["Temperature"]. "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

Last 10 results:

[image: Last 10 results]

Now, I'm trying to check if last 10 rows in "Temperature" column are the same (as we can see).

I use:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT Temperature, COUNT(*) as duplicates FROM AllinOne GROUP BY Temperature ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

if ($result2->num_rows > 0) 
{
  // output data of each row
  while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) 
  {
    echo $row2["duplicates"]. "<br>";
  }
}
```

but I can't take back the same results (i can't understand the final result).

$row2 results

[image: $row2 results]

Could you help me???

Comment: The final $row2 results is a list of counts of each temperature value stored in the database. If you show the temperature value too (i.e. `echo $row2["Temperature] . " - " .$row2["duplicates"]. "<br>";`) it will be clearer what it's showing. But since it's an aggregate query, `LIMIT 10` isn't doing what you probably imagine it is...it limits the _query results_ to 10 rows, it doesn't limit it to counting only the last 10 source rows. You should probably test your queries directly in mysql before worrying about the PHP side of it.

Comment: Building from your first query (= `SELECT ID, DayTime,Temperature FROM AllinOne ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10`): why dont you loop over all results in PHP and just check whether all `$row["Temperature"]` are the same?

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal because temperature is changing continuously it's impossible have the same temperature evey time. So, if the temperature values are the same, I know that my system has a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the following query and grab the result:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS count_rows,
    MIN(Temperature) AS min_temperature,
    MAX(Temperature) AS max_temperature
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM t
    ORDER BY DayTime DESC
    LIMIT 10
) AS x
```

Then send an email if `count_rows = 10` and `min_temperature = max_temperature`.

Comment: `if($row2["count_rows"] = 10 AND $row2["min_temperature"] = $row2["max_temperature"])` is the right syntax???

Comment: No. Use `==` instead of `=` to compare and `&&` instead of `AND`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. 

`if($row2["count_rows"] == 10 && $row2["min_temperature"] == $row2["max_temperature"]){
    
    echo "The module is stucked. Please RESET it!!!";
    
    $message= "The module is stucked. Please RESET it!!!";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
else 
{
    echo "No Stuck";
}`. That's my code. Have exactly the same condition as in first photo.

Comment: it needs to be a separate php question. I might be able to help if you post the result of `var_dump($row2);`

Comment: In a new question or edit this question?

Comment: New question would be better. Impossible to read code inside comments.

Comment: The anser in `echo (var_dump($row2)). "<br>";` is NULL. 
I don't know how to title the new question.

Comment: Post the code you're using and title it something like "MySQLi query not working as expected". Post debugging information if possible (people will tell you what to post).

Comment: Finally, I solve the problem. I added the code from 3rd comment in while condition. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix your second query like:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT Temperature, COUNT(*) as duplicates 
    FROM (
        SELECT ID, DayTime, Temperature FROM AllinOne ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10
    ) LastData
    GROUP BY Temperature";
```

[Here you can test PHP code with queries](https://phpize.online/?phpses=0cfa50e488a620956df6cfc4b8c22cbe&sqlses=6f39c997d8cf9f58a0a8e9bb03dcc32a&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Again, zero result. Maybe because i haven't the same time in every row.